# Is Access required on client machine to view Access reports via Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access

If I publish an Access database to Sharepoint, does the end user need Access installed on their machine to view the reports?

Comment: There is no *released* version of Sharepoint that allows the user to run an Access database published via Sharepoint without Access being installed. Sharepoint 2010 with A2010 changes that, but the expected release for those is not until mid-year 2010 (the current Office 2010 is the release candidate, so things are very close; code is likely to go gold very soon).

Comment: It possible the term published is being used to describe the process in 2007 of publishing tables to SharePoint. Unfortunately the term used for this upsizing of tables was often called publishing in 2007.

http://blogs.msdn.com/access/archive/2006/09/18/761366.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re talking about access 2007, and SharePoint 2007, then yes they still have to install and have the Access client installed on their local desktop machines. SharePoint will not really help you here.

There’s also the possibility of using SQL server reporting services here. In a nutshell this setup would have you using the desktop access application with the backend data on SQL server. You then setup Reports using the web based version of the SQL server reporting services. You then simply have the users view those reports with a web browser. In fact, in this setup you would NOT be using SharePoint, And in fact in this type of scenario, SharePoint really would not help you here.

However, if you’re talking about SharePoint 2010, and Access 2010 and the access 2010 web Publishing ability? In this case when you publish access applications and those reports to the web, then any standard browser can consume and view those reports (you don’t need any part of office or access Installed on the client computer, just a standard web browser. So even a non windows computer such as a Mac or even Linux will work in this case).

I suppose, it’s probably interesting to point out that those reports that you publish with Access web Publishing are in fact based on and utilize SQL server reporting services.

Looking at this from strictly just being able to view the report’s on the web, SharePoint 2010 would be a possible solution. At the end of the day, your report’s will be running under SQL server reporting services.  Of course if you did use Access 2010 then you’ll be able to design those reports inside ms access as opposed to having to use the SQL server report designer.

So the way I see this, SharePoint 2007 not simple in the box solution here.  However, you can most certainly set up and use SQL server reporting services from SharePoint, and if your lists and data is published in Access 2007 to SharePoint 2007, then that would work (Of course, you’ll not be building the reports in access, but this setup will work with published access 2007 data to SharePoint).

I would have to suggest that if you don’t already have SharePoint 2010 and acces 2010 setup, I don’t think one can justify Setting up SharePoint just for the very sole purpose of being able to publish your Access reports, when you could in theory use SQL server reporting services without the time and expense of having to set up SharePoint 2010.

However, in the case that you’ll have SharePoint 2010 running, with Access 2010, then it’s a no brainer…you just Publish your Access reports to SharePoint, and you’re sailing.